# Preview Typescript literal types on React props using VSCode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I've got this literal type:

```js
type ModalSize = 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
```

and I use it for a React component prop.

However, the preview I got when the mouse hovers it with VSCode is this:

[image]

Is there a way to see the literal type, with its values (`small`, `medium`, `large`), in the preview, instead of `size?: ModalSize`?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the literal type directly to your props like this:

```
type Props = {
    size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
}
```

and extract it as a type with `NonNullable` to make sure that you dont get the undefined option since `size?` could be undefined like this:

```
type ModalSize = NonNullable<Props["size"]>;
```

And you could export it if you want to use the type in other functions that need those exact values, if it is done outside your component!